# using anonymous functions in R with multiple arguments

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, anonymous-function

I'm attempting to generate new variables in a data frame that are conditional on two (or more) other variables in the data frame. I believe that the looping functions in R (i.e., lapply, sapply, etc.) are useful and efficient for this purpose. Something is not right, however, with my approach, and I can't figure out what.

```
M <- data.frame(x=c("A", "A", "B", "B"), y=c(1,2,1,2))
```

Using this data frame, I would like to generate a new column z, containing logicals that are TRUE iff both `x == "A"` and `y == 1`. The following code is the best I can come up with here, but only seems to evaluate my first condition.

```
M$z <- sapply(M$x, function(x,y) if((x == "A") && (y == 1)) T else F, M$y)
```

- Can this code be fixed for my purpose?
- Is there a better way of doing this in R, perhaps using other looping functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a task for `transform` function

```
transform(M, z=ifelse((x == "A") & (y == 1), T, F))
  x y     z
1 A 1  TRUE
2 A 2 FALSE
3 B 1 FALSE
4 B 2 FALSE
```

I think an even simpler approach would be

```
M$z <- with(M, (x == "A") & (y == 1))
M
  x y     z
1 A 1  TRUE
2 A 2 FALSE
3 B 1 FALSE
4 B 2 FALSE
```

Comment: That's a way more efficient way of solving the problem.  @tfarkas Native vectorization is almost always better than using `apply`.  Even simpler: `M$z<-ifelse((x == "A") & (y == 1), T, F)`

Comment: Why not just `M$z <- M$x == "A" & M$y == 1`? - Nevermind... your edit does essentially that. I just wasn't a fan of the whole `ifelse(conditional, T, F)` construct because you're just outputting what was in the conditional anyways.

Comment: from efficient to positively minimalist! Thanks so much everyone. Why can't I accept any of these as answers? For the record, i like the ifelse() construct best, because it's computationally efficient, and general (so that it could output objects of any mode). Cheers!

Comment: @AriB.Friedman `ifelse` isn't really vectorised, any more than `apply()` et al are. It is iterating over the vector, but it is not the same as the truly vectorised operations using `==` and `&` as shown in the edit to this Answer.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Agreed.  Path dependence fail.

Comment: `ifelse` looks vectorized to me. It makes vectors of the yes and no outcomes and indexes them using the conditional, so it's not a fundamentally different approach.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman IMO, `ifelse((x == "A") & (y == 1), T, F)` is just silly. Whenever you put `TRUE` and `FALSE` within `ifelse`, it's a sign that you're not doing it right. Simple `&` should be just fine (or `&&` FWIW). Note however, that `ifelse` returns: _A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and ‘"class"’) as ‘test’ and data values from the values of ‘yes’ or ‘no’._ So yeah, it applies length coercion too.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at mapply:

```
> M$z <- mapply(M$x,M$y, FUN=function(x,y) if((x == "A") && (y == 1)) T else F)
> M
  x y     z
1 A 1  TRUE
2 A 2 FALSE
3 B 1 FALSE
4 B 2 FALSE
```

Apropos, this has nothing to do with anonymous functions and everything to do with applying with multiple arguments.  If you named the function it would still not work in any of the single-argument apply variants.

The other way to do this would be to `ddply` by row, or split your data.frame into a list with each row being a separate entry.

Comment: i thought all the looping functions had a "..." argument that passed extra arguments to the function?

Comment: @tfarkas `mapply` does as well.  Since I've passed an argument name for the function, that matches even though it's in the first position.  Then everything else gets wrapped into `...`.